# Diamond-printing program in Java creating an infinite loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop

I'm having some problems with printing a filled diamond. The program incorrectly formats the diamond.

This code:

```
      for (rows = 1; rows < height; rows += 2){

            for (spaces =0; spaces < height - 1 - rows / 2; spaces++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (stars = 0; stars < rows; stars++){
                System.out.println("*");
            }
        }
```

prints out this:

```
Please enter a positive odd height for the diamond:
9
    *
   *
*
*
  *
*
*
*
*
 *
*
*
*
*
*
*
```

Edit: I've got the top half of the diamond done, but I can't seem to get the bottom half down. It creates an infinite loop.

```
for (rows = 1; rows < height  + 1 ; rows += 2){

            for (spaces =0; spaces < height - 1 - rows / 2; spaces++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (stars = 0; stars < rows; stars++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        for (rows = 1; rows < height; rows -= 2){

            for (spaces =0; spaces < height; spaces++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (stars = 0; stars < rows; stars++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

EDIT 2: Fixed the infinite loop, but now the stars are unaligned:

```
for (rows = 1; rows < height  + 1 ; rows += 2){

            for (spaces =0; spaces < height - 1 - rows / 2; spaces++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (stars = 0; stars < rows; stars++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        for (rows = height - 2; rows >= 1; rows -= 2){
                for (spaces =0; spaces < height; spaces++){
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

                for (stars = 0; stars < rows; stars++){
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
```

OUTPUT:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
     *******
     *****
     ***
     *
```

EDIT 3:
Got the stars aligned, just need to get rid of middle row.

code:

```
for (rows = 1; rows < height  + 1 ; rows += 2){

            for (spaces =0; spaces < height - 1 - rows / 2; spaces++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (stars = 0; stars < rows; stars++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        for ( rows = height; rows > 0; rows -= 2){

            for ( spaces =0; spaces < height - 1 - rows / 2; spaces++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for ( stars = 0; stars < rows; stars++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
```

Output:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

Comment: Post what is the expected output.

Comment: Your second inner loop should use `print` instead of `println`. Put `println` after the second inner loop ends.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0080__Statement-Control/PrintoutaDiamond.htm

Comment: I've updated my answer with the fixed code. It should get rid of the duplicate line in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code has a few problems.

Firstly, you're using this:

```
System.out.println("*")
```

instead of this:

```
System.out.print("*")
```

In Java, `println` and `print` are two different things. `println` automatically adds a newline at the end of the string, whereas `print` does not.

However, you can't just change `println` to `print`, since then all the output will be on one line. Every time you run through the loop, use `System.out.println()` to create a newline.

You also don't define `rows`, `spaces`, and `stars` (I'm assuming they aren't defined elsewhere.) You can define them in the for loop, like so:

```
for (int rows = 1; rows < height; rows += 2) {
```

As for the bottom half of the diamond, you can simply reverse the for loop and leave out one line (the middle line, since that was created by the first loop.) Here is the start of the second for loop, the contents are the same as the first:

```
for (int rows = height - 2; rows > 0; rows -= 2){
```

Instead of starting at 0, adding 2 and continuing until we reach `height`, we start at `height - 2`, subtract 2, and continue until we reach 0.
Why `height - 2` and not `height`? That's because if we use `height`, it will print a duplicate row. `height - 2` removes one row (the duplicate) and prints the rest of the bottom half.

Here is the complete fixed code:

```
    for (int rows = 1; rows < height; rows += 2){

        for (int spaces =0; spaces < height - 1 - rows / 2; spaces++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int stars = 0; stars < rows; stars++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

        for (int rows = height - 2; rows > 0; rows -= 2){

        for (int spaces = 0; spaces < height - rows / 2 - 1; spaces++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int stars = 0; stars < rows; stars++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Let me know if anything is inaccurate or unclear.

Comment: I still get the middle line twice.

Comment: @ChrisNedworth In the second `for` loop, try replacing `int rows = height` with `int rows = height - 1`.

Comment: That makes it worse. the lines become unaligned and it gets rid of the last row.

Comment: @ChrisNedworth I've edited my post with a fixed version of the code, it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

For your updated question, you get an infinite loop because your for loop

```
for (rows = 1; rows < height; rows -= 2)
```

only decrements rows (from 1), and checks for less than.

Try something like:

```
for (rows = height; rows >= 1; rows -= 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class diamond {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int i,n,j,k,l=0;
        System.out.println("enter number n");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=in.nextInt();

        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<=n-i;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(k=1;k<=i;k++)
            {
            System.out.print("*");

            }
            for(l=2;l<=i;l++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for(i=n;i>=1;i--)
        {
            for(j=0;j<=n-i;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(k=1;k<=i;k++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for(k=2;k<=i;k++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case if you are looking to accept input from user,a small change and the code would look like above

Comment: What you've written as comment should be part of the answer. Please edit and read the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to improve your future answers.

Comment: Thanks Gala,will definitely take care of it,slightly new here,getting used to it.

Comment: No problem! Have a look at the help center, you will find many usefull helps on how to ask/answer :)

Answer (score -2):

Code :

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
        System.out.print(" ");

      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print("*");

      System.out.print("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 7; i > 0; i -= 2) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
        System.out.print(" ");

      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print("*");

      System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Output :

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *
```